# Integral involving error function and exponential

Tags: indefinite-integrals, error-function

I have not been able to find a source that gives this indefinite integral:
$$ \int e^{-(a+x)^2}\text{erf}(b+x)\,dx.$$

Can someone provide a source or a formula (with our without demonstration)?

Comment: Writing down a "random" function, you will observe that most of them will not have an antiderivative in terms of known functions. You have better chances for definite integrals. Unless you provide some background why you are interested in this antiderivative and/or some reason why you expect that this problem has a solution, I vote to close.

Comment: i think there is no solution in the known Standard functions

Comment: This integral appears in some calculations I am doing that's all. The integration is from 0 to an arbitrary constant $c<\infty$. I know that a "random" function may not have an antiderivative but a lot of very complicated indefinite integrals involving special functions exist so I was wondering if this one, which doesn't look that awful, had a solution..

Comment: Is the gaussian exponential the derivative of the error function, in some sense? Perhaps, proceeding carefully, there might be a way to perform something along the lines of "u-substitution"?